# How to add a Calculated Item(Not Field) with PowerPivot whilst pointing to the DataModel

Tags: excel, powerpivot, datamodel, powerquery

[Desired Pivot Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXNaE.png)

After loads of searching I'm still trying to find a way to add a Calculated Item to a PowerPivot Table, from the Data Model.

I'm essentially looking to create a profit row that will display as a row after calculating the difference between cost and revenue.

I can do it when the data is coming from a worksheet but the "Calculated item..." option is greyed out when trying to do it from the Data Model.

I'm not looking at adding a field(column) I want to add a calculated row in essence that forms part of the pivot table.

Any help as to whether this is possible would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: Please post some code or show us what you have tried so far. Also refer to this link for tips on posting a question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9imJEO2IT-8&feature=youtu.be this is what I can already do when the data is in the worksheet. Problem arises when you are using data from a data model, this functionality is greyed out and I cannot seem to create a calculated row, surely there is a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

In Power Pivot you do not use pivot table functionality to accomplish this sort of thing, rather we add measures to the data model that encapsulate our business logic.

Some reading on measures in Power Pivot [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399077(v=sql.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [2](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/02/when-to-use-measures-vs-calc-columns/).

Comment: Thanks greggy b, I'm still not clear as to how to use PowerPivot (in any way) to create this summary row. I can Create variance columns between Actual and Budget, I can create SamePeriodLastYear Measures that also display as columns, but I want to also be able to combine Row selections to produce summaries.  I can obviously use multiple PowerPivot tables to achieve this, but I REALLY want to avoid this. Are you saying that it's not possible to achieve the layout I'm looking for? Or are you saying I need to use a different method? Thanks Jon

Comment: You can display measures on columns or on rows, just move the "Values" field from the column label section to the row label section of the pivot table designer.  If instead you want to just add a dummy value to a field and write a measure around that, you can do so. See this discussion for an example of what I mean. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2edf7041-acee-4560-b852-1232891baf15/is-it-possible-to-create-a-pivot-table-report-based-on-power-pivot-that-has-different-resolution-for?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel

Comment: Alternately, you could just create a hierarchy (you'd have to add the appropriate columns to the table in question) that rolls up the row label values appropriately, and you'd get the behavior you want out of pivot table subtotals.

Comment: Just so I know I'm understanding you correctly, are you suggesting to add calculated columns to the PowerQuery to include additional levels in the hierarchy? Maybe it's just because it's late in the day, but I can't seem to figure this one out in my head. Apologies

Comment: The first comment suggests adding values to the table. Make it taller, and handle the specific value with a conditional evaluation, as linked in the forum post. The second comment brings up an alternative of adding an additional field to the model (this can happen before Power Pivot, or as a calculated column), then this field could group the values in another field. Seeing as we have no idea what your model looks like, or what your measures are, it is very difficult to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a calculated field or a calculated item in a PivotTable based on OLAP source data. I presume that is what you are trying to do. Here is a detailed article that explains the differences: differences-between-olap-and-non-olap-pivottables-in-excel https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234700

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add calculated fields to a PowerPivot Pivot Table. Any additional calculations that you may need should be added to the PowerPivot model with DAX.

info is from the bellow link.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/10-differences-between-powerpivot-pivot-table-standard-teneva